# Cannot get object in specific index in Java

Tags: java, android, sql, database, list

I am creating simple Android project which contains login `Activity`. The problem is I tried to reach the object in specific index and tried `for` loop, but it always return last object in sequence.

```java
 public Result<LoggedInUser> login (String username, String password){

    try {
        // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
        GetData myData = new GetData();
        usersdata = myData.getUsers();
        for (User user : usersdata) {
            if (user.UserName.trim() == username && user.Password.trim() == password) {
                LoggedUser = user;
            } else LoggedUser = null;
        }

        return new Result.Success<>(LoggedUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are compared with `equals`, not with `==`.

Comment: And the `else` block will be invoked - break out of the loop as soon as the `user` is found.

Comment: its true iremoved the else block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has three problems:

1. Comparing the strings using `==` which compares the references and not the content of the strings
2. Not breaking the loop when the intended result is found.
3. Executing `LoggedUser=null;` in the `else` part of the `if` where you are comparing the strings. As a result of this, `LoggedUser` is set as `null` even when the intended result is found at any position other than the last position. You should do it once the loop terminates.

Do it as follows:

```
public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {
    boolean found = false;
    try {
        // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
        GetData myData=new GetData();
        usersdata=myData.getUsers();
        for (User user:usersdata) {
            if(user.UserName.trim().equals(username) && user.Password.trim().equals(password)){
                LoggedUser=user;
                found = true;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if(!found) {
            LoggedUser=null;
        }
        return new Result.Success<>(LoggedUser);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks gays the main problem was in the initialization of 'usersdata' must be inside loop because of these error the array filled by the same values each loop and i removed the else block because it breaks my code

Answer (score 0):

We use .equals with strings as we compare references :

```
    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(String username, String password) {

    try {
        // TODO: handle loggedInUser authentication
        GetData myData=new GetData();
        usersdata=myData.getUsers();
        for (User user:usersdata) {

   if(user.UserName.trim().equals(username)&&user.Password.trim().equals(password)){
                LoggedUser=user;
            }
            else LoggedUser=null;
        }

        return new Result.Success<>(LoggedUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

```
username != null && password != null
```

Then use .equals() to compare the Strings (not == )

```
user.UserName.trim().equals(username.trim())&&user.Password.trim().equals(password.trim())
```

The reason why you received the last user in the sequence might have been, that both users were null, because then the if-statement would resolve to true for each iteration of the loop.